# Is there a memory limit that we can configure in Hazelcast for all maps combined?

Tags: hazelcast

I would like to know if there is a memory limit that we can configure in Hazelcast for all maps combined. Say at the instance level. 
Since my hazelcast node runs embedded inside my app's JVM, I would like to put this restriction

Answer (score 1):

How would that work when you reach memory limit? Which map will evict the entries?

Since you're starting hazelcast with defining a heap size you can use heap usage based eviction on all maps. Or you can just use a single map only if you want to have a single eviction configuration.

Answer (score 1):

@Haresh, you have an option to define eviction policy for `USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE` or `FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE` as described here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-map-eviction

You need to define this eviction config for all map configs & `default` map config as well. This'll help you to limit heap usage but can cause other unexpected behaviors as @sertug mentioned.

Assume that you have 2 maps: `a` and `b`. You fill up `a` and only have enough room for 1 more entry in the JVM. When you start pushing data to `b`, it'll only store the last one & evict the previous one since a map can only evict a record from its own, not from a different map.